# Android Adding an Event to calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I want to put a button in my android application. When user taps the button it should open a default popup screen where we can enter starttime , endtime etc to save an event to personal calendar.

I am new to android development so I am unable open that popup screen in my application 
can any one help me out in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

The extra parameters are optional of course, they will just fill in some initial values on the form. You can chose to add them or remove them yourself.

Also I'm not sure but I think you need permission:

```
<uses-permission
   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR">
   </uses-permission>
```

Comment: when i tried this on my emulator it is crashing  at startActivity(intent).

Comment: Is it possible that the emulator just doesn't have the Calendar application? Also does it work on real devices?